# actionBarSize different in xml and code

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a view with height defined as:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Later on this view will have to be resized to a larger format and eventually back to the original, so in the onCreateView of the fragment I do:

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
int actionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle()
```

Which, as far as I understand, should be the exact same value as i initially got in the XML.
This is however not the case, the value from the XML is 112 while in code it returns 96.
 
Anyone any clue why this is or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

doc for getDimension(int,int) says
Retrieve a dimensional unit attribute at index. Unit
conversions are based on the current DisplayMetrics
associated with the resources this TypedArray object
came from.

I think may be the displaymetrics associated with that does not work.
So try

```
float pixelvalue = styledAttributes.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
float dpValue =pixelvalue/ getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Answer (score -1):

In case use ActionBarSherlock/AppCompat use:

```
?attr/actionBarSize
```

Why use?:

```
final int actionBarSize
```

why dont use?

```
actionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

this last option give you the value at runtime.